# googleweblight not executing OnClick JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, googleweblight

Following JavaScript call function not working in **googleweblight**

```
<a href="javascript:FBLogin();" class="btn btn-sm azm-social azm-btn azm-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook ID</a>
```

or

```
<a onclick="FBLogin()" href="#" class="btn btn-sm azm-social azm-btn azm-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook ID</a>
```

What may be issue? is it possible to fix it?

For a example
http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/Yazpj/1/ It will work,

but same link wont work in
googleweblight http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/Yazpj/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript seems to be disabled in googleweblight, if you want to see in detail then you can look at your site by this

> `http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=[your_website_URL]`

example http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://stackoverflow.com/

Well, you can opt out of it but in such case google will label your page in the search results to indicate to users that non-transcoded pages may take longer to load and may use more data.

You can find more details here
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211428?hl=en